# binary with string in Python

Tags: python

I'm python beginner.
I wrote this code but it can't work successfully.
Someone can understand why?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # if "pro" begin with "test", delete "test" from "pro".
    pro = "001001111010010101001"
    test = "0010"

    if pro.startswith(test):

        pro = pro.lstrip(test)
        # My ideal -> pro == "01111010010101001" 

        print pro
    print pro
```

This code doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`str.lstrip()` removes *all characters* that appear in the *set* of characters you gave it. Since you gave it both `0` and `1` in that set, and the string consists of *only* zeros and ones, you removed the whole string.

In other words, `str.lstrip()` does **not** remove a prefix. It removes one character at a time, provided that character is named in the argument:

```
>>> '0123'.lstrip('0')
'123'
>>> '0123'.lstrip('10')
'23'
>>> '0123'.lstrip('20')
'123'
```

Remove the first `len(test)` characters instead:

```
pro = pro[len(test):]
```

Comment: Thank you so much everyone!!
I could do it as my ideal.

Answer (score 2):

`lstrip(chars)` returns a copy of the string in which all chars have been stripped from the beginning of the string. so if you pass `test` that contain 1,0 it remove all the characters from `pro` (`pro` contain only 0,1) .

```
>>> pro = pro.lstrip('10')
>>> pro
''
```

instead you can Just use slicing :

```
>>> if pro.startswith(test):
...    pro=pro[len(test):]
... 
>>> pro
'01111010010101001'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because lstrip removes all of the left characters from the set given so removes everything:

I think that you need:

```
pro = pro.startswith(test) and pro[len(test):] or pro
```

this will remove `test` from the start of `pro` if it is there.

Comment: If you are going to make it a one-liner then at least use a conditional expression: `pro[len(test):] if pro.startswith(test) else pro`.

Answer (score 1):

Just as extra.. This will also work:

```
>>> pro = "001001111010010101001"
>>> test = "0010"
>>> if pro.startswith(test):
       pro = pro.partition(test)[-1]
       print pro

01111010010101001
```

Comment: I think `pro = pro[len(test):]` might be more clear than using `pro.partition()`.